# Multiple variables in sample function in R

Tags: r, sampling, dice

I am trying to use the sample function in order to produce the number of times the number "3", would appear if I "roll the dice" N times. 
For example if I want the frequency of the number 3 after N times. But I am trying to do this after N times, N +10, N+20 until N+200.
So in other words, the frequency of the number 3 after 10, 20, 30, 40 ... 210 rolls. 
But instead of copying the code each time and changing the value of N, is there a more efficient way to do this?
So this is the code:

```
N=10
e1= sample(1:6,N,rep=T)
e11=(e1==3)
sum_e11=sum(e11)
relative_freq= sum_e11/N
relative_freq
```

Comment: If you only plan on only drawing one sample for each size `N` then the result won't be an accurate relative frequency. You'll want to take the average of many samples of the same size `N`. Otherwise, your current approach only shows a possibility for how many 3's could be rolled.

Comment: That is fine, but is there any better way to check all rolls (N+10 and so on) rather then copy and past the code each time I wish to change the N?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that covers both options. Set `iterations = 1` for the single sample approach you originally posted about. The more iterations, the more mathematically accurate the frequency will be. The `sapply` function will run the function at each of the values in the sequence from 10 to 200, by 10.

```
relative_freq <- function(target,N,iterations=10000){
  result <- logical(iterations)
  for(i in 1:iterations){
    samp <- sample(1:6,N,replace=TRUE)
    result[i] <- sum(samp==target)
  }
  mean(result)
}

relative_freq(3,10)
relative_freq(3,20,1)

sapply(seq(10,200,by=10),function(n){relative_freq(3,n)})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply` and `seq` to run your function for `10, 20, 30, 40 ... 210`.

```
set.seed(7)
sapply(seq(10,210,10), function(N) sum(sample(1:6, N, replace=TRUE) == 3)/N)
# [1] 0.3000000 0.2500000 0.1000000 0.1250000 0.1400000 0.1666667 0.1714286
# [8] 0.1250000 0.1444444 0.0800000 0.1727273 0.1916667 0.1461538 0.1857143
#[15] 0.1666667 0.1437500 0.1588235 0.1888889 0.1631579 0.1800000 0.2285714
```